# SQL server PHP PDO COUNT field incorrect or syntax error

Tags: sql-server, pdo

I didn't want to post this but last resort.

PHP with MS SQL Server 2008 and I'm getting an error of: [SQLSTATE[07002]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error
Here is my code:

```
    $server_name = 'sqlserver';
    $user = 'user';   
    $passwd = 'pass';

    $sqlString = "INSERT INTO dbo.tbl (UniqID, rideid, stopRatingId, category, ddescription, rating, createdDate) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$server_name;Database=db;ConnectionPooling=0", $user, $passwd);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sqlString);

    $sqlVals = "'1', '233', '34', 'Delivery', 'Data Integrity', 'Good', '2018-07-11 08:34:21'";
    $stmt->execute(array($sqlVals));
```

The array shows:

```
print_r(array($sqlVals));

Array ( [0] => '1', '233', '34', 'Delivery', 'Data Integrity', 'Good', '2018-07-11 08:34:21' )
```

when I try this, the insert is successful without error:

```
$stmt->execute(array('1', '233', '34', 'Delivery', 'Data Integrity', 'Good', '2018-07-11 08:34:21'));
```

Not sure how to correct - any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In First example $sqlVals is treated as 1 string value not distinct values

so you can try this

```
$sqlVals = array('1', '233', '34', 'Delivery', 'Data Integrity', 'Good', '2018-07-11 08:34:21');

$stmt->execute($sqlVals);
```